# Altair to generate horizontal bar chart with horizontally concatenated table

Tags: python, altair

If possible, I would like to use altair to create a horizontal bar chart with a column or columns from a table that is horizontally concatenated and aligns with the bar. I'm pasting an example of quick excel chart to get a rough idea of what I'm wanting.

[image: example]

The following example from your website (code and then image), which I subsetted for the sake of space, is similar to what I would like. However, rather than have a text overlay with the value corresponding to the bar length, I want to create a horizontal bar chart with value "x" and a horizontally concatenated table with a separate value, "p", that corresponds to that sample.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()
sourceTrunc = source.head(15)

bars = alt.Chart(sourceTrunc).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y="year:O"
)

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='wheat:Q'
)

(bars + text).properties(height=400)
```

[image: foundation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [horizontal concatenation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#hconcat-chart) in place of layering to achieve this. For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()
sourceTrunc = source.head(15)

bars = alt.Chart(sourceTrunc).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y="year:O"
)

text = alt.Chart(sourceTrunc).mark_text().encode(
    y=alt.Y('year:O', axis=None),
    text='wheat:Q'
).properties(width=30)

bars | text
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. this works. But I do have a follow up. Since it is encoded as a y-axis, adding a title puts it along the left side of the y-axis (hence why you probably declared it is 'None'). Is there a way to put a title on top or bottom so that it looks column-ish?

Comment: That sounds like you were setting the axis title. If you want a chart title, use ``.properties(title='the title')``

Comment: @jakevdp: a bit of an old qustion but still - would it somehow be possible to interactively sort the column (with the chart ofc)? thx!